# Easiest way to validate this input?

Tags: javascript, validation, input

Still fairly new to JavaScript trying to validate some text field input, I've been trying to do it step by step but there's a lot going on and I keep contradicting myself. I've explained the required validation below.

```
var a = document.getElementById("val1").value;
var b = document.getElementById("val2").value;
```

val1 and val2 refer to two text input fields, a and b both have to be positive integers, but only one input field has to be filled, in that case the other variable should be given the value 0, then variable a should be the smaller of the two values and b the largers, in order for me to run the following loop.

```
for (var i = a; i < (Number(b) + Number(1)); i++) {
    tableRow = resultsRows.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));
    if(i%2==0) {
        tableRow.setAttribute("class", "even");
    }
    else {
        tableRow.setAttribute("class", "odd");
    }
    var tableData = tableRow.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));
    tableData.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
    tableData = tableRow.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));
    tableData.appendChild(document.createTextNode(converter(i)));
}
```

Function I was trying to write to validate this. Not sure how to accept blank input with this...

```
function validateInput(x) {
    if (isNaN(x) || x < 0) {
        alert("Input incorrect; fields must be blank or contain positive integers");
        return false;
    }
    else { return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using to perform the validation.  There are many different validation libraries and the answer will depend on what you already have in place.

Comment: Has it already been checked that only one of them would be greater than zero? Or are you looking for ways to accommodate that check too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the attached code snippet.
It is designed to incorporate the following assumptions:

- Only one of the numbers must be entered (i.e. both fields can't be left blank at the same time, nor can both contain the values together) **AND** it must be positive
- No non-numeric input

```js
function customValidation(){
    var a = document.getElementById("val1").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("val2").value;

    if((a == "" && b == "")
        || (a > "" && !isNumber(a)) || (b > "" && !isNumber(b))
        || (a < 0 || b < 0)
        || (a == 0 && b == 0)
        || (a > 0 && b > 0)){
        alert("Input incorrect; "
               + "only one of the fields must contain a value "
               + "and that should be a positive number");
        return false;
    }
  
    if(a > 0){
        n = a;
    }
    else{
        n = b;
    }

    for(i=0; i < (Number(n) + Number(1)); i++){
        alert("Executing: "+i);
        //
        //
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------
```

```html
Val1: <input id="val1" type="text"><br>
Val2: <input id="val2" type="text"><br>

<input type="button" value="Test" onClick="customValidation()">
```